# I can't know how to use image on stackoverflow

Tags: iphone

I inserted image on stackoverflow to ask some questions
When I click post button,the error happens as following
"You need at least 10 reputation to post images"

It would be very thankful ,if you let me know the way how to fix this problem
Very Thank you

Comment: Related Meta Stack Overflow post: [Why can't users with less than 10 reputation points add images while asking question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268469/why-cant-users-with-less-than-10-reputation-points-add-images-while-asking-ques)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question belongs on Meta Stack Overflow post (but is too old for site migration)

Answer (score 0):

If you answer questions here, or ask *really well thought out* good questions, you'll get points and your reputation will increase.

And answering just one question with a good answer will get you your 10 points.

And then you'll be able to post images in your questions.  Remember, you should also contribute answers and help to your fellow participants here, don't just ask questions.

[Here's the "how to ask questions" FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/about).

Answer (score 0):

Even without the reputation needed for posting images here, you can upload the image somewhere else, post your question here and put the link to your screenshot in the question.

Answer (score 0):

@user2948579
(answering the Title of the post)
You can use std. HTML like this

img src="http://example.com/sample.png" width="100" height="100"

I don't know how you would upload the image directly to stackoverflow, it assumes you have it on some other image store.

More Found here:
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#images)